# rails3, clean url, friendly_id, sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, clean-urls, friendly-id

I'm using friendly_id it works wonderful I add a new private action to my events controller to make sure only events owner can update their events...my show and delete action works fine but when I do an update I get an error

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EventsController#edit
Couldn't find User with ID=snow-board

any suggestions to fix this ?

```
## Events controller
..scaffold generated code
private

 def correct_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(:controller =>'events', :action => 'edit',:id => session[:user_id]) unless current_user?(@user)
 end

## Event view
 link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) 

## Even Model

has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
...validation code

## Session Helper

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work (use from_param and not find)?

```
 def correct_user
   @user = User.from_param(params[:id])
```